# VCRUNTIME140.dll has been installed but is still missing

Tags: apache, regsvr32

Trying to install Apache 2.4 (httpd.exe -k install)

Keep getting: **The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem**

I have tried to manually insert the .dll file into System32 folder and run the using **regsvr32 vcruntime140.dll** and it doesn't work.

I have tried installing, reinstalling and restarting my computer for **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 RC** to no avail.

Much appreciated if anyone can be of assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the 64bit **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 RC** and was still getting the error, so I installed the 32bit version and it worked.

(Sorry for the spam)